# Extracting Embedded <span> in Python using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, extract, data-science

I am trying to extract a value in a span however the span is embedded into another. I was wondering how I get the value of only 1 span rather than both.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


some_price = page_soup.find("div", {"class":"price_FHDfG large_3aP7Z"})
some_price.span

# that code returns this:

'''
<span>$289<span class="rightEndPrice_6y_hS">99</span></span>
'''

# BUT I only want the $289 part, not the 99 associated with it
```

After making this adjustment:

```
some_price.span.text
```

the interpreter returns

```
$28999
```

Would it be possible to somehow remove the '99' at the end? Or to only extract the first part of the span?

Any help/suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the desired value from the `soup.contents` attribute:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
html = '''
 <span>$289<span class="rightEndPrice_6y_hS">99</span></span>
'''
result = soup(html, 'html.parser').find('span').contents[0]
```

Output:

```
'$289'
```

Thus, in the context of your original `div` lookup:

```
result = page_soup.find("div", {"class":"price_FHDfG large_3aP7Z"}).span.contents[0]
```